# How do I change the object type of an object?

Tags: java

I´m trying to change the object salaDeEspera[i] from Paciente to Enfermo as the salaDeEspera array is Pacientes type and I wanna put it inside the habitaciones array which is Enfermos type

```
public void atender(Pacientes[] salaDeEspera, Enfermo[] habitaciones, Enfermeros enfermero1, Doctores doctor1) {
    

    for (int i = 0; i < salaDeEspera.length; i++) {
        enfermero1.examinar(salaDeEspera[i].getNombre());
        doctor1.atender(salaDeEspera[i].getNombre());
        if (doctor1.enfermo==true) {
            habitaciones[i]= salaDeEspera[i].getNombre();
        }
```

Comment: Without knowing anything about the types it's impossible to say - that is domain specific. I imagine you'll need to implement some kind of `static Enfermo fromPaciente(Paciente p) {...}` method to create a new object from the old one.

Comment: You cannot change the type of an Object - an object is what it is.  You can create a new Object based on the old one.   However, its not obvious what you are actually trying to do here because 1. class/variable names are in Spanish, 2. characteristics and relationship of types is not defined here, 3. class/variable names seem inconsistent so intent is not clear.

Comment: Depending on whether it makes sense for your architecture, one solution could be to have both implement the same interface.  But as mentioned, impossible to tell.

Answer (score 1):

You can't (literally) change the type of an object.   Its fundamental type is fixed (for ever) when it is created.

You *may* be able to create a new `Enfermo` from the state of a `Pacientes`.  But you are creating a new object, not changing the type of an existing object.

You *may* be able to wrap a `Pacientes` inside an `Enfermo` ... but once again you are creating a new object.

You *may* be able to cast a `Pacientes` to an `Enfermo` ... but only if:

- the type `Pacientes` is a supertype of `Enfermo` and the object is *really* a `Enfermo` already, or
- the type `Enfermo` is a supertype of `Pacientes`.

I don't think we can be more specific without details of what `Pacientes` and `Enfermo` are, what they mean, how they are related, and .... how you are actually using them.

Answer (score 0):

You can either create a method that copies the data from the first type to the second... OR create another class that contains the common data of each class and have your own classes extend that class. Example:

```
public class people {}
```

and then add this to both your classes

```
public class Pacientes extends people {}
```

for your function, you can pass in the type people

```
public void atender(people[] salaDeEspera, people[] habitaciones, Enfermeros enfermero1, Doctores doctor1) {
...
}
```

!!Be aware that you'll need to actually type cast them in the function.